# VS2008 remote debugger: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

I'm trying to set up remote debugging for a VirtualBox VM running XP SP3, following [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/visual_studio_remote_debugging.html).

On the guest OS I've started the remote debugging server:

[image]

I have verified that I can connect to the server using netcat:

```
C:\Users\sashoalm>ncat.exe myorgani-1bd08e 4015
Hello?
W Çclose: No error
```

But when I try to connect from the *Debug->Attach to Process...* dialog (I put `myorgani-1bd08e` for the Qualifier), I get this error:

> Unable to connect to 'myorgani-1bd08e'.  An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about this error say this:

> WSAEACCES
>   10013
>   Permission denied.
>   An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. An example is using a broadcast address for sendto without broadcast permission being set using setsockopt(SO_BROADCAST).
>   Another possible reason for the WSAEACCES error is that when the bind function is called (on Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later), another application, service, or kernel mode driver is bound to the same address with exclusive access. Such exclusive access is a new feature of Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later, and is implemented by using the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Maybe the socket is held by some process. Use netstat -o to find which one

Comment: I ran it on the guest machine, it showed only one socket - `TCP    myorgani-1bd08e:1157   192.168.0.108:netbios-ssn  TIME_WAIT       0`

Comment: The funny thing is, if I write a hostname that doesn't exist, it gives me `Unable to connect to ...`, but if I type an IP address in the form `192.168.0.xxx`, it gives me `An attempt was made to access a socket ...` even if there is no computer with that IP on the network.

Comment: do you try to use ip instead of hostname in VS to connent to the remote debugger?

Comment: I tried both. Giving an incorrect hostname gives me `Unable to connect to ...`, giving the correct hostname gives me `An attempt was made to ...`, the tutorial suggested using hostname instead of IP btw. Also, netcat can connect to the server fine. It's there and it's listening. Maybe VS2008 tries to use some esoteric permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it turned out to be the firewall **on my own computer** that was preventing Visual Studio from making outbound connections (there was an outbound rule for devenv.exe, and I have no idea how it got there).